# can i have a code for zoom effect upon hover on these images in the div class below

Tags: html

this is container that i created for my images,the container is at the bottom of the page before  the footer

```
<div class="team-work">
    <div class="container">
        <h3 class="team">Gallery</h3>
        <div class="team-grids">
            <div class="col-md-3 team-grid">
                <img src="images/trans3.jpg" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 team-grid">
                <img src="images/trans1.jpg" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 team-grid">
                <img src="images/trans4.jpg" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 team-grid">
                <img src="images/trans5.jpg" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please embed your CSS code for the elements.

Answer (score 0):

i have created small example for you to understand also about the image zoom on hover...

> What i have used is **TRANSFORM** to **scale the image** (same effect like
>   zooming) with pure CSS, that gives the normal to zoom effect on hover.

Hope this helps you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
     <style type="text/css">
      .team-grid {
       display: block;
       overflow: hidden;
      }

      .team-grid img {
       -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
       -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
       -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
       -o-transition: all .5s ease;
       transition: all .5s ease;
      }

      .team-grid img:hover {
       transform:scale(1.5);
       -ms-transform:scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
       -moz-transform:scale(1.5); /* Firefox */
       -webkit-transform:scale(1.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
       -o-transform:scale(1.5); /* Opera */
      }

     </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="team-work">
      <div class="container">
       <h3 class="team">Gallery</h3>
       <div class="team-grids">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 team-grid">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 team-grid">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000" alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 team-grid">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000" alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 team-grid">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000" alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in between the `<head></head>` tags of your document.

```
<style type="text/css">

.team-grid{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
 .team-grid img {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.team-grid:hover img {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
    transform:scale(1.25);
}
</style>
```